# Common tool to build app using any platform

Tags: java, c#, vb.net

Applications can be build using any of these platforms (C#,vb,java), Is there any specific tool that supports development of app for any of these platform. For example why is that a cab file project or exe   is developed using visual studio and android application are developed using eclipse which gives us app with .apk extension. for example if we have to concentrate our code developed using C# or vb or java , it has similarity except that it changes the syntax or naming nomenclature to define data or subroutine call. like printf in C, write or writeln in C# or println in java. or stream classes like filestream, or inputstream and outputstream,bufferedstream.........etc..... Is it that one tool for all application in the world . compiler does a common functionality in all this tool then why cant we have a common tool?

We wished for a tool xyz that supports C#,Java,vb or any other platforms and that has inbuilt virtual machine that has emulators to supports it respective apps. Also the result file must be of standard format with a standard extension that supports all types of OS Instead of exe,or cab or .apk or .dll . Just a thought . we have standard format for data tranfers via web , why not this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The issue with the tool:**

MS Editor or any other basic text editor allows you to write applications in any of the mentioned plattforms. You then just need the required plattform base (like the JDK) as well as the compiler and interpreter of all of those plattforms. (Not to mention a Host-OS supporting the compilers/ interpreters).

Now that thats been said ("Yes there is a Tool for all of them"), i think it is only logic that  IDEs focusing only on certain plattforms. Most of them will also allow to write applications in similar plattforms, like eclipse will support C, C++, C#, Java and so on.

This i guess is the case because most of the developpers on the market are specialized on one plattform only.

It is not that it is not possible to go any further into that direction but more that with any plattform supported complexity of the UI will increade (so will the available Short-cuts) 
and thatfore lowers the usability of the IDE itself.

A simple example would be a view in the UI where you configure your Debug-Settings for local debugging. Would you implement it with tabs for each plattform or try to build a generic UI for all of them? It would lead to tabs i guess because debugging information of Java programm will surely require different configurations than when it comes to debug a Eiffel Programm.

So we would have a IDE that is

- to complex to use as Beginner
- to complex to find the required things as specialist of Plattform XY
- to slow when it comes to handle the filesystem state for multiple projects using different plattforms.
- to complex to develop and keep track with all the requirements of SWEs of the different plattforms.
- to complex to maintain all the changes in the different languages supported.

But i gladely be teached wrong and try out such an IDE.

**The nature of the plattform**
(Answer to Question: "What about the deployment", see below)

See most programming languages are designed to work with certain operartion systems (like Visual Basic works with MS Windows), because those operation systems provide a bunch of APIs and allow you to use their "core"-functionality like "copy a file from dir a to dir b". The sequence of 0s and 1s (as faar as i know any OS basicially needs assembled 0/1s unless its a quantum computer or a machine one would not commonly describe as "computer") beeing executed by a CPU to copy a File from A to be will defently differ on Windows, Unix, OSX etc.

By its nature it will in my eyes never make sence to have a Java Programm beeing represented in Eiffel or Fortran even thus there are Projects working on "Programming Language A to B translators.

But i dont think that is what you are thinking of right, you just want to sit at one computer only and be able to deploy and run all kind of programms on it.

Since the different plattforms will require different operation systems or an according environment to run on them (like Java can be run on OSX, Windows, Unix etc.) you would need something like a virtual machine per desired plattform.

When it comes to super old programming languages or stuff that "wont run on your OS" there oftenly is Emulators available that bring the needed things with them.

Comment: so that means we can develop both android and windows mobile app using one tool Editor. But what about deployment . Is it possible to deploy both apps in different OS. what about compatibility.

Comment: I updated my answer but i am not sure if i can follow you one hundred percent.

Comment: Agree, I wished for a tool xyz that supports C#,Java,vb or any other platforms and that has inbuilt virtual machine that has emulators to supports it respective apps. Also the result file must be of standard format with a standard extension that supports all types of OS Instead of  exe,or cab or .apk or .dll . Just a thought . we have standard format for data tranfers via web , why not this.

Comment: I see that point and i assume in 5-10 years we will either have way more or way less points that allow a productive and efficient solution in that way. To have a OS-independant format alone is one thing but like it happens in Java today you will have a relatively large and required JVM installed to be able to run Java on a System.    Just imagine how large this part on the host system would become to be able to guarantee it will be able to execute nearly any technology such as Eiffel, Phyton, Java, C, C++, .NET. And then there is a bunch of "dynamic" languages such as XL o.O

Comment: I enjoyed this exchange a lot, have a good day :)